# How can i remove all characters started with # from a textarea using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code below

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" rows="10" placeholder="Description..." class="valid"> 
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And i want to remove all this content.
</textarea>
```

how can i remove only this text from the textarea

```
# And i want to remove all this content.
```

using jquery or javascript ?

As you can see i want all the content that start with a hashtag to be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only for textarea, you may use a simple Regular Expression, with "m" (multiline) flag.

• Where `$` means end of the line;

• special `.` matches with any symbol, 

• `*` means 'match from zero to infinite times'

```js
let desc = document.getElementById('description');

desc.value = desc.value.replace(/#.*$/gm,"");
```

```css
textarea {width: 80%;}
```

```html
<textarea class="js-replace" id="description" name="description" rows="10" placeholder="Description..."> 
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And i want to remove all this content.

Bubu and replace #Me
But not me!
</textarea>
```

Version for multiple elements, textarea, div, etc - replace by className:

```js
let replace = document.querySelectorAll('.js-replace')

for( let i = 0; i < replace.length; i++ ){
  let area = /TEXTAREA|INPUT/.test(replace[i].tagName); // will return true or false;
  let content = area ? "value" : "innerHTML";
  // Ternary operator. (condition) ? (value if true) : (value otherwise)
  
  // replace[i]['value'] if textarea and replace[i]['innerHTML'] if other element
  replace[i][content] = replace[i][content].replace(/#.*?(\n|<br>|$)/g, "$1"); // (*1)
}
```

```css
textarea {width: 80%;}
```

```html
<textarea class="js-replace" id="description" name="description" rows="10" placeholder="Description..."> 
This is an example text i wanna keep. 
# And i want to remove all this content.

Bubu and replace #Me
But not me!
</textarea>

<div class="js-replace">
  This is an example text i wanna keep. 
  <br># And i want to remove all this content.
  <br>
  <br>Bubu and replace #Me
  <br>But not me!
</div>
```

(*1): `.replace(/#.*?(\n|<br>)/g, "$1")` — string, starting from `#` symbol, matching `.*` anything (instead of line-break `\n`), many times, and `?` stop as soon as it faces with `\n` line break `|` or `<br>` HTML-line break. `"$1"` — equals to match in the first (parentheses). I.e. we replace all string, but keep line-break.

But this will not work correctly, if you want to delete, for example, comments from Python... because you may delete strings with `"str... # str"`

Comment: Good solution, but it would help to educate the OP and all future visitors if you explained how it worked.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME this works absolutely perfect. Additionally how can i use the code you provided to remove content from an element (not only a textarea or an input field) ? Once again thanks.

Comment: @Designer depends, how you will define line-breaks. `<br>` or `white-space: pre-line;` ?

Comment: i guess <br> will be ok